# VueJS + NuxtJS + Vuetify - Text size not applied

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuetify.js

I have the following component

```
<v-card v-for="item in items">
  .
  .
  <v-card-title class="text-button" v-text="item.category" />
  .
  .
</v-card>
```

However the `"text-button"` class is not applied.

According to the `vuetify` docs there are several font size classes, `h1`, `h2` etc but none of them work. But adding `class="text-uppercase"` or `class="text-underline"` or any of the other classes **does work** the only thing that wont work are the font size classes, which is extremely inconvenient as they offer a shorthand for device sizes  (`text-xl-h2`) and such.

If it helps, this here is the style from inspecting the element

```
.v-card__title {
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    font-size: 1.25rem;
    font-weight: 500;
    letter-spacing: 0.0125em;
    line-height: 2rem;
    word-break: break-all;
}
```

the `font-size` is **always** `1.25rem` no matter what. If I modify that value by hand, the text size changes. So possibly the problem is this `1.25rem` value, which I am **not** setting anywhere and I have no idea where it is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just copied the `v-card` Vuetify example and applied the class to the `v-card-title` without a problem [Codepen](https://codepen.io/nicolasdurant/pen/abBRgLV). Which Version of Vuetify are you using? If you are using 1.5.x, `text-button` doesn't exist there and text-classes get applied differently, I can't tell you on which 2.4.x Version it came, but I think this might be the issue. Are other `text-{values}` classes working for you, like `text-h1`?

Comment: npm install @nuxtjs/vuetify@next will update vuetify to latest